# `new WebSocket("wss://example.com:8080")` sending blank headers to backend (PHP server, Javascript Client websockets)

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket, stream

I'm moving to upgrade the web sockets on my page to use a secure connection. However, when I call `new WebSocket()` with a `wss://` instead of `ws://`, there are no headers being sent at all.

This is what I have so far:

php:

```
$lcNull = NULL; //null var
$lcHost = '0.0.0.0'; //host
$lnPort = '8080'; //port
$lcCertPath = '/path/to/cert';

//Create TCP/IP stream socket
$lhContext = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($lhContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $lcCertPath);

stream_context_set_option($lhContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'something');
stream_context_set_option($lhContext, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($lhContext, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

$lsSocket = stream_socket_server(
  "ssl://0.0.0.0:$lnPort",
  $errno,
  $errstr,
  STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
  $lhContext
);


if ($errno > 0) { //An error has occured
  echo("Main socket error ($errno): $errstr");
  die();
} else {
  echo("Main socket started, listening on $lcHost:$lnPort");
}

//create & add listening socket to the list
$laClients = array($lsSocket);
$laSocketUser = [];

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {

  //manage multiple connections
  $laChanged = $laClients;
  //returns the socket resources in $laChanged array
  stream_select($laChanged, $lcNull, $lcNull, 0, 10);

  # User Connected!
  if (in_array($lsSocket, $laChanged)) {

    $lsSocketNew = stream_socket_accept($lsSocket); //accept new socket
    print "accepted " . stream_socket_get_name($lsSocketNew, true) . "\n";
    $laClients[] = $lsSocketNew; //add socket to client array
    echo "\nReading header:>";
    stream_set_blocking($lsSocketNew, true);
    $lcHeader = fread($lsSocketNew, 5000); //read data sent by the socket

    echo $lcHeader . "<\n\n";

    ...
```

And the output depends how the web socket is created in the Javascript:

this sends headers:

```
var wsUri = "ws://"+window.location.host;   
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

this sends *nothing* :P (i.e. the php above echos out `Reading header:><`, meaning it did not receive any headers.)

```
var wsUri = "wss://"+window.location.host+":8080";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

So my question is: Why does the wss:// example not send any headers, and how can I get it to send the headers correctly?